# Link quebrado para o histórico em resposta com spam

Tags: bug, status-pronto, tradução, internacionalização

Me deparei com [um spam postado como resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/51123/132) que linkaram no chat para excluirmos e também para podermos dar um pouco de risada da sua ridicularidade. Tal resposta foi automaticamente e corretamente excluída como spam pelo usuário [Comunidade ♦](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/-1/comunidade) após a conta do usuário ter sido removida/destruída pelo bfavaretto. Por este motivo, ela só é visível para usuários com reputação alta e moderadores.

Atualmente ela apresenta o seguinte texto:

> Esta resposta foi marcada como spam ou ofensiva e portanto não será mostrada - você pode ver **o histórico de análises** para detalhes.

Há um link no texto "o histórico de análises", este link tem o seguinte formato:

```
https://pt.stackoverflow.com/publicações/CODIGO-DA-RESPOSTA/análises
```

Tentar acessar este link causa um erro 404. Neste caso o link não deveria ter sido traduzido, e o link correto é esse:

```
https://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/CODIGO-DA-RESPOSTA/revisions
```

Comment: Isso já tinha acontecido [aqui](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/2392/link-quebrado-na-fila-de-autoavalia%C3%A7%C3%A3o-do-site). Parece que estão usando variáveis do sistema de tradução para montar o URL.

Comment: neste caso: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/51123/revisions

Comment: Mais um exemplo: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/51213/7210

Comment: @AnnaLear any particular reason to change the tags into English? Just curious...

Comment: @Math Argh, that was not intentional - just a side effect of Chrome's page translation. I changed them back. I hope. Thanks for asking. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This will be fixed in revision `2015.3.17.2390`.